# Convert a datetime in vb .net application

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, date, datetime

I have a problem in the  datetime format conversion. In My table of Database i have a column `jour` with a format like this :

```
01/02/2014 00:00:00
```

ie `DD/MM/YYYY 00:00:00` . When i do this :

```
        Dim date1 As String = Session("date1")
        Dim date2 As String = Session("date2")
        Dim datefirst As DateTime
        Dim dateSecond As DateTime
        Try
            datefirst = DateTime.Parse(date1)
            dateSecond = DateTime.Parse(date2)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        Dim report As ReportDocument = New ReportDocument()
        Dim reportPath As String = Server.MapPath("Reports\Prix.rpt")
        Dim ds As DataSet
        Dim cnn As SqlConnection
        Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=HP-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ReportingFormation;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"
        Dim sql As String = ""
        Dim dscmd As SqlDataAdapter
        cnn = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        cnn.Open()

        sql = "SELECT * FROM PrixProduit where ( Jour >= '" + datefirst + "'and Jour <='" + dateSecond + "')"
        dscmd = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn)
        ds = New DataSet()

        dscmd.Fill(ds, "PrixProduit")
```

With these values :
 **date1**= `30/01/2014` 
 **date2** = `06/02/2014` 
 **datefirst** = `#1/30/2014#` 
 **dateSecond**= `#2/6/2014#`

So i got this error

`The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.`

in this line of code :

```
dscmd.Fill(ds, "PrixProduit")
```

So i need to know

- What is the reason of this error?
- How can i fix it?

Comment: Database column's format should be irrelevant here...

Comment: @Crono Can you explain more your idea plz

Comment: You say your database column has a specific date format. How is it so? If it's a DateTime type (as it should be) then there's no database format of any kind, no?

Comment: You're storing a date as a string in a Session variable?  You should store it as a `Date` (or `DateTime`).  Then you won't have to do a `String` to `DateTime` conversion.

Comment: Yes my DateTime columns takes this specific format `DD/MM/YYYY 00:00:00`, i don't know why

Comment: You should use `parameterized` query to avoid `SQL injection` and at the same time solve your formatting problem, that is, with single quotes.

Comment: @DMason i change my code like you said `Session("date1") = DateTime.Parse(date1)
            Session("date2") = DateTime.Parse(date2)` ==> i have this same error because of the difference of formats

Comment: This is what I had in mind for storing a DateTime in a session variable: `Session("date1") = date1`.  And this is what I meant for retrieving a DateTime from a session variable `Dim date1 As DateTime = CDate(Session("date1"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case you have two option, first is to change `date` in application to match `date` in database. Second is to include style during the `convert`. Below is example of trying to `convert` `varchar` to `date` field. First `select` will fail. But second one will work because I'm specifying the `style` that I'm expecting the string to be.

```
DECLARE @datechar VARCHAR(12) = '16/03/2014'

SELECT CONVERT(DATE, @datechar)

SELECT CONVERT(DATE, @datechar, 103)
```

You would need to modify your SQL code to the following

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM PrixProduit where ( Jour >= Convert(date,'" + datefirst + "',103 ) and Jour <= Convert(date,'" + dateSecond + "',103))"
```

Just like people already mentioned you should avoid concatenation of the strings that makes your app prone to sql injection. Therefore modify the code to this.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM PrixProduit where Jour >= Convert(date,@datefirst,103 ) and Jour <= Convert(date,@datesecond,103)"
```

after that just add parameters to your command.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you use US datetime format MM/DD/YYYY. Change this line to:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM PrixProduit where ( Jour >= '" + datefirst.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "' and Jour <='" + dateSecond.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "')"
```

ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") converts the datetime to the format MM/dd/yyyy explicitly to avoid the default conversion, which might not be what we want.

I should also point out that in your explanation:

"With these values :  date1= 30/01/2014 date2 = 06/02/2014 datefirst = #1/30/2014# dateSecond= #2/6/2014# ...."

The value in date1 is '30/01/2014'. If this is not a typo, you probably get the error

```
"The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value."
```